# Jquery delay link redirection for ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

When a link is clicked, I want to clear the php session before redirecting to the destination page.

The way I thought of doing it is by loading a php script that clears the session with ajax in the origin page and once that script has loaded, to redirect to the destination page.

Here is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        var clearSession = "clearsession.php";  
        $("#content").load(clearSession,"");
    });
});

<a href="destination.html">
```

Currently it seems to follow the link before the php script completes loading.

A few guidelines :

2. You can't make the link point to any other page than "destination.html"
3. You can't add variables to the destination page either (destination.html?clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [load callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) so you can execute the redirection after you receive a response.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        var clearSession = "clearsession.php";  
        $("#content").load(clearSession,"",function(){
            window.location = $(this).attr("href");
            return false;
        });
    });
});

<a href="destination.html">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought of that but couldn't seem to get it right. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just redirect to clearsession.php?link=destination.html, which clears the session and then re-redirects to the desired URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        var clearSession = "clearsession.php";  
        $("#content").load(clearSession,"");
        return false;
    });
});
```

With *"return false;"*, the browser won't follow the link.